# method overloading - function __call($method, $arguments) PHP

Tags: php, overloading

This is my first time using Stack... and I am really new at PHP... but here is my problem:

```
<?php
class Address {
    private $street;
    private $city;
    private $state;

    function __construct($s, $c, $st) {
        $this->street = $s;
        $this->city = $c;
        $this->state = $st;
    }
    function setCity($c) {
        $this->city = $c;
    }
    function getCity() {
        return $this->city;
    }
    function setState($s) {
        $this->state = $s;
    }
    function getState() {
        return $this->state;
    }
    function setStreet($s) {
        $this->street = $s;
    }
    function getStreet() {
        return $this->street;
    }
}
class Student {
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $address;

    function __construct($n, $a, $s, $c, $st) {
        $this->name = $n;
        $this->age = $a;
        $this->address = new Address($s, $c, $st);
    }

    function getName() {
        return ucwords($this->name);
    }

    function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }

    function setName($n) {
        $this->name = $n;
    }

    function setAge($a) {
        $this->age = $a;
    }

    function __set($name, $value) {
        $set = "set".ucfirst($name);
        $this->$set($value);
    }

    function __get($name) {
        $get = "get".ucfirst($name);
        return $this->$get();
    }


    function __call($method, $arguments) {
        // JUST NEED CODE HERE TO SOLVE FOR THE PROBLEM
    }


}
$s = new Student('john smith', 50, '100 main street', 'Sunnyvale', 'CA');
echo $s->name;
echo "\n";
echo $s->age;
echo "\n";
echo $s->street . ", " . $s->city . ", " . $s->state;
echo "\n";
$s->street = "50 second street";
$s->city = "Palo Alto";
echo "The address has been updated:\n";
echo $s->street . ", " . $s->city . ", " . $s->state;


$s = new Student("John", 30, new Address("San Jose", "CA"));
$t = clone $s;
$t->name = "Jack";
$t->address->city = "Santa Clara";
echo $s;
echo "\n";
echo $t;
?>
```

And I am after this answer but I can only add code to the function __call

> John Smith
>   50
>   100 main street, Sunnyvale, CA 
>   The address has been updated:
>   50 second street, Palo Alto, CA

hope someone can help!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: His question is that he needs code for the function __call, so that when ever he calls it, he passes parameters and then the address of john smith should be updated.

Comment: Improve your question brother, it will give you downvote :( its not self discripting :( Regards.

Comment: Try to be a bit more generic about your problem so that we can get what exactly you need.

Comment: "but I can only add code to the function __call" - because homework?